# get a tabular view on a page for a document library

Tags: 2013, document-library, sharepoint-on-prem

Hello i am using SharePoint 2013 on-prem

I have created a document library containing all documents related to a product.

Then i created a page, added the webpart of the document library, thereby showing the library. And by web editing I then can grant a specific view to such a list to show on that page.

However I'd like to have tabular view in which i configure some of the predefined views. ea a view for sales, engineering, marketing, etc.

how can i achieve that ?.
So the some views are under specific tabs

Comment: You can try this: http://www.topsharepoint.com/dynamic-bootstrap-tabs-for-sharepoint see Step 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the best example to show any list/library view in Tabbed form.

[SharePoint Tabbed Web Parts–HillbillyTabs 3.0](http://www.markrackley.net/2015/08/16/sharepoint-tabbed-web-partshillbillytabs-3-0/)

You can add your different views of same library in each tab for sales, engineering, marketing, etc. as you per your need.

Comment: Marked as answer, as its not possible by default Sharepoint, what comes most close in sharepoint as a way of sorting is the groupby option. 
(ps still need more points to raise your asnwer).

Comment: No Worried. It is important that my answer helps you... :)

Comment: Your answers help me a lot, ive used Sharepoint before but never this deep in this specific direction. They want me to build something pretty complex, if i manage i might get a job here. But their not easy on me i'm in job trial period now.
Currently breaking my head on how to make it work that a webpart filter determines lookup column for drag drop on a doc library.